# My application color look with lines when

Tags: wpf, remote-access

Please see this `screenshot`:

[image]

As you can see there is several 'lines' around my application `Background`, this when i connect to the machine that running my application using `Remote Desktop` or `Radmin`.

This is when i am running my `application` on my local machine:

[image]

Any suggestions how to avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

it is just remote access when connecting to a machine via remote access it doesn't give you the best picture. You could probably change the colour inside remote desktop settings it might give you a better picture but thats just the down side of using remote access

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the maximum color depth for a remote session, if the RDP session is hosted on a server. See the following article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772048.aspx

You also need to verify that Remote Desktop Connection options for Display have the Highest Quality (32 bit) color depth setting.

[image: mtsc]

Also, The experience tab could be detecting a slow connection, and downgrading the quality. You can explicitly set the connection type to limit this behavior.

[image: mtsc2]